# match field from multiple lookup in aggregate

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate-functions, lookup

I have a query for doing a lookup on two other collections, one contains information about students, other contains information about classes. The collection I'm running the query contains information about activities.

The things is: I can't compare a field from the second lookup I've done (on classes), for some reason the fields I add don't seem to work on the `project` field either.

Here's my query:

```
[
      {"$lookup":{
        "from":"students",
        "localField":"class_id",
        "foreignField":"classes_registered",
        "as": "std"
      }},
      {"$unwind":"$std"},

      {"$addFields":{"id_cls":{"$toString":"cls._id"},
                    "cls_name":"$$cls.name"
                  }},
      {"$lookup":{
        "from":"classes",
        "localField":"class_id",
        "foreignField":"id_cls",
        "as": "cls"
      }},
      {"$unwind":"$std"},

      {"$match":{
        "$expr":{
          "$and":[{
            "$eq":["$std.email", filters["email"]]
            },
            {
            "$eq":["$cls.name", filters["class_name"]]},
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {"$project":{
        "_id":0,
        "cls.name":1,
        "title":1,
        "info":1,
        "date_start":1,
        "date_final":1,
        "list":1
      }}

    ]
```

"cls.name" shows always as "[ ]" on the response from query and

`"$eq":["$cls.name", filters["class_name"]},`

also doesn't compare to anything.

student collection sample:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"60e3bfef0046de182072361d"},
"name":"matheus",
"date":{"$date":"2021-07-06T02:29:03.974Z"},
"email":"math@math",
"classes_registered":["60b4753f7976fb83300918f0","60b477557976fb83300918f2"]}
```

classes collection sample:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"60b477557976fb83300918f2"},
"name":"desenho",
"teachers":["60b474937976fb83300918f1","60b474937976fb83300918ee"],
"date":{"$date":"2021-05-31T05:42:45.232Z"}}
```

classes_activities sample:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"60e4c88ee19fb3797390b3f9"},
"title":"Trabalho Discente Efetivo II",
"info":"Desenhar em perspectiva cavallera a formiga apresentada em aula",
"date_start":{"$date":"2021-07-06T02:00:00.000Z"},
"date_final":{"$date":"2022-07-06T02:00:00.000Z"},
"list":1,
"class_id":"60b477557976fb83300918f2"}
```

Comment: What does the `$project` show for just the field `cls`?

Comment: You should really add document samples so it's easier to recreate it.

Comment: @prasad_ it shows  "cls: [ ]" when I write "cls.name":1